# Google Compute Engine Firewall Rules Are Broken

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall

I have a google compute engine instance with a windows os installed. I just add a firewall rule to gce and then delete it. But after that I could not reach my website. Then I tried to reach from rdp but it also cannot reach to instance.

I tried to update default rules without changing them but It doesn't help. Somehow, Firewall rules are broken but now it is default state. It still continues not working.

Is there any way to make working rules again?

Comment: Have you tried running `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

- If the instance has the same tags as the firewall rules.
- If the instance has the ports open. You can run nmap scan for open ports in a  CloudShell for this, but need to install nmap fisrt:
  Install nmap:

> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get install nmap

Scan for any TCP/UDP open port

> $ sudo nmap -sS -sU [instance's IP]

or scan a specific port status:

> $ sudo nmap -Pn -p [port] [instance's IP]

- It will also help debugging to check the serial output console of the instance.

Comment: Hi, I tried that instance has a green tick near its name but command says "Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-09 14:40 EAT
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.05 seconds"

Comment: with Pn parameter it says "Nmap scan report for ***.***.***.***.bc.googleusercontent.com (***.***.***.***)
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on ***.***.***.***.bc.googleusercontent.com (***.***.***.***) are filtered"

Comment: You have to specify the port with the option Pn to get the ports status (80 for http, 443 for https and 3389 for rdp).

If the ports are open, try stopping and starting the instance, this will recreate the VM in another host machine.

If the issue persist check for errors in the serial port output.